Extending CircuitPython (Simple Example) how to complete
I was building Circuitpython from the github repro from adafruit.
This was working for a raspi pico well. I could compile and dounload the firmware.uf2 -> Thonny everthing look OK.
Next I wanted to add a C-written module. Doing as described by adafruit was OK until the point:
ports/atmel-samd
We'll need to edit two files to hook our new module into the build:
Makefile
We need to add  the c files we added to shared-module to the SRC_SHARED_MODULE list:
mymodule/init.c 
mymodule/MyClass.c \
I do not know where to find the SRC_SHARED_MODULE list and where to make the changes?
Thank you for the help.
Tips where to insert then module name
